# How should i write query to display data from two table Like

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to get data from two tables:

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | John |
|  2 | Alex |
|  3 | Able |
|  4 | Ash  |
+----+------+

+------+------+
| name | sale |
+------+------+
| John |  100 |
| Alex |  200 |
| Able |  300 |
| Able |  100 |
| Alex |  500 |
+------+------+
```

Retrieve all Agent name from 1st table and sum of sales from second table. If any user sale is not there then it must give me null or zero value.

[The output is something like shown in image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIdtA.png)

Answer (score 1):

To return null values in the case of no sales you can use a left outer join.

```
SELECT
      agent.name
    , SUM(sale) AS totalSales
FROM
    agent
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sale ON agent.name = sale.name
GROUP BY
      agent.name
```

If you would prefer the value to be zero you can use the coalesce or isnull functions

```
SELECT
      agent.name
    , COALESCE(SUM(sale),0) AS totalSales
FROM
    agent
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sale ON agent.name = sale.name
GROUP BY
      agent.name
```

Comment: i want more help to use this query to apply in datalist. i use bellow code :        string str = "SELECT Agent.name , COALESCE(SUM(TotalSale), 0) AS totalSales FROM Agent LEFT OUTER JOIN NewSales ON Agent.Name = NewSales.Agent GROUP BY Agent.Name";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            DataList1.DataSource = ds;
            DataList1.DataBind();
            conn.Close();

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your exact problem is as you haven't specified. However, that aside, in the snippet you've posted in this comment, should SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); actually be SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(str, cmd);?

Comment: i used above code to retrieve data and <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TotalSale") %>'></asp:Label> this code to display data in datalist but it gives me error : DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'TotalSale'.

Comment: that's because your select statement returns a field that was aliased as totalSales, not TotalSale.

COALESCE(SUM(TotalSale), 0) AS totalSales

Comment: OK, this isn't my specialty (the SQL part is) and I don't have enough information about your problem to be able to help you. I'd suggest asking another question, or editing this one, giving all the necessary detail about your form structure and the code behind it which you are you're using to populate it. Basically everything you'd need to debug someone else's problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a left join, since you want a row for every salesperson in your result. So, like:

```
SELECT a.name, SUM(s.sale)
FROM Agent a
LEFT JOIN Sale s on a.name = s.name
GROUP BY a.name
```